# Rails 4 undefined method `import' for #<Class:0xa874498> when importing csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) railcast on how to import a csv file.

My csv file is called **stg_pound.csv** and has the following contents:

```
"FOREX RATES FOR DATES BETWEEN 2003-5-1 AND 2014-5-28, STG POUND",,,,
 Date,Currency,Buy,Sell,Mean
 01/01/03,STG POUND,147.5117,147.7939,147.653
 01/02/03,STG POUND,147.837,148.1767,148.007
 01/03/03,STG POUND,147.8006,148.1422,147.971
 01/04/03,STG POUND,148.0311,148.3722,148.202
```

my app is setup as follows:

my forex index.html.erb :

```
 <%= form_tag import_forexes_path, multipart: true do %>
   <%= file_field_tag :file %>
   <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
 <% end %>
```

forexes_controller.rb

```
def import
  Forex.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Imported"
end
```

forex.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: forexes
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  published_at :datetime
#  currency     :string(255)
#  buy          :float
#  sell         :float
#  mean         :float
#  created_at   :datetime
#  updated_at   :datetime
#

def import
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Forex.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :forexes do
  collection  { post :import}
end
```

application.rb

```
require 'csv'
```

When I try importing the **stg_pound.csv** file I get the following error:

```
 undefined method `import' for #<Class:0xab2c6cc>
```

The following line from the forex_controller.rb file is highlighted:

```
 Forex.import(params[:file])
```

However I can see the file has been picked since on the error page I'm seeing the following:

```
 Request

 Parameters:

 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mGm6jN7uvoRVjVbSDE/vpprIQnpjiL60s4rETHT9mPA=",
 "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa974dc @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140530-4261-z8fb9x>,
 @original_filename="stg_pound.csv",
 @content_type="text/csv",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"stg_pound.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">,
 "commit"=>"Import"}
```

At first I thought it was because :file had not been included in the strong_parameters so I went ahead and included the following in forex_controller strong parameters but it doesn't work

```
def forex_params
  params.require(:forex).permit(:published_at, :currency, :buy, :sell, :mean, :file)
end
```

Comment: Give your `import method` in your model like this `self.import(file)`

Comment: Worked but why does it not work if I don't prefix my model method with self and its in Rails 4?

Comment: Yeah just saw it after I asked the question

Comment: If it is not prefixed with `self`,then that method is treated as `instance method` but not `class method`.You need to define it as `class method` to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your import method is an instance one, it needs to be class.

```
def self.import
  # content
end
```

Secondly, you are passing parameters to it from the controller `Forex.import(params[:file])` but not catching them.

```
def self.import(file)
  # content
end
```